# How to run sql query that use "for json" and "for xml" in sql server?

Tags: apache-nifi

I want to run a complicated SQL query that use "for sql" and "for xml" in microsoft sql server. I used ExecuteSQL, but it got me this Error:

```
ExecuteSQL[id=87f3d800-016c-1000-28be-8d99127d267e] Unable to execute SQL {my sql query} for StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=ef1bc7c3-2e48-4911-abea-52e9b5a432b2,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1565651606554-2, container=default, section=2], offset=176, length=8],offset=0,name=ef1bc7c3-2e48-4911-abea-52e9b5a432b2,size=8] due to org.apache.avro.SchemaParseException: Illegal character in: XML_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B; routing to failure: org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: org.apache.avro.SchemaParseException: Illegal character in: XML_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B
```

How can I get the result as JSON or XML in apache NiFi?
[Format Query Results as JSON with FOR JSON (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Could you share your query?

Comment: I can't share original query, but it is something like this: 
`USE Music;
SELECT TOP 2 ArtistName,
    (SELECT AlbumName 
        FROM Albums
        WHERE Artists.ArtistId = Albums.ArtistId
        FOR JSON PATH) AS Albums
FROM Artists
ORDER BY ArtistName
FOR JSON PATH`

Comment: Can't you use run query using ExecuteSQL without json/xml clause and then pass the flowfile thru 'ConvertRecord' processor to convert data in json/xml as needed?

Comment: no @Pushkr, I generate nested jsons.

Comment: @daggett is there a way to use groovy script?

Comment: for sure it's possible, but i have no idea (experience) how mssql gives this json to a client. is it a one row with one column resultset that contains json? and what is the datatype - varchar?

Comment: You could find several example here:
[for json example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-nested-json-output-with-path-mode-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: according to [ssa-data](https://www.ssa-data.com/blog/archive/sql-server-2017-json/) _Support for JSON on SQL Server is initially available for all editions. At the same time, Microsoft has not considered a separate data type, as in the case of XML. JSON on SQL Server are stored as strings: in Unicode (NVARCHAR / NCHAR) or in ANSI (VARCHAR / CHAR) format._

Answer (score 0):

note: i have no experience with such queries and how they are returned to the client.

i assume that server returns one row and one column with string containing json (or xml)

in this case the script for `ExecuteGroovyScript` could be like this:

```groovy
def ff=session.get()
if(!ff)return

def query = '''
   SELECT TOP 2 ArtistName, 
   (SELECT AlbumName FROM Albums 
      WHERE Artists.ArtistId = Albums.ArtistId FOR JSON PATH) AS Albums 
   FROM Artists ORDER BY ArtistName FOR JSON PATH
'''

ff.write("UTF-8"){writer-> 
    SQL.mydb.eachRow{row->
        writer.append( row[1] ) //get first column from the row
        writer.append('\n')     //expecting 1 row but just in case add separation for the next row
    }
}
//transfer to success
REL_SUCCESS << ff
```

to make `SQL.mydb` available for the script - create property with this name and connect it to corresponding DBCP: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C83f5.png